# Как передать сумму в POS терминал?

Tags: c#

Пишу аналог кассового терминала для Windows. Для оплаты используются наличные или карта. Чтобы оплатить картой, нужно с компьютера (из приложения) вывести итог на POS терминал. Все помнят ли, когда на кассе кассир нажимает на кнопку и итог загорается на POS терминале автоматически? Хотелось бы именно так реализовать данную опцию.

Comment: Что-то я подозреваю, что лучше об этом спросить у создателей вашего POS-терминала

Comment: Зависит от конкретного POS терминала, смотрите документацию, спрашивайте производителя. Большинство из них общаются с компьютером по COM порту, либо его эмуляцию по USB.

Comment: Т.е. если импортировать .dll файл (драйвер) и оттуда выскребать нужные API, то можно будет общаться с POS??

Comment: Этих данных Вам не хватит. Большая часть поступающих в ПОС данных, обрабатывается самим ПО ПОС. Плюс протоколы общения с процессингом и 3DES-шифрация данных с пин-пада

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо ПО по программированию POSа, документация по нему и языку общения с POSом. ПО у каждого производителя разное. Для verifone это posloader.
Возможно, могу чем-то поспособствовать (работал с верифонами и инпасами). Но обычно банк осуществляет настройку.

Comment: Ну тут и проблема, хех, я перешёл в 11ый, и такой проект, написать свое ПО (касса), для винды, на Visual Studio (C#), не знаю, как вот общаться с POSом...

Comment: В 11-ом классе написать кассовую программу с модулем взаимодействия с ПОСом?!!!!! Что за школа?!!!!  Можете сразу ответить преподавателю, что обучающие материалы по написанию модулей к ПОСам в свободном доступе отсутствуют. Они бы ещё попросили Вас написать модуль к картридеру банкомата!!!!

Comment: Сообщаю это как банковский служащий (IT).